# How can I restyle the listings caption to a tcblistings environment?

Tags: listings, tcolorbox, code, tcblisting

I am trying to define a tcblistings environment that should work under the following syntax...

```
\begin{code}{TITLE}{LANG}{CAPTION}{OPTS}
code here
\end{code}
```

Everything but the language should be optional. I want to add a listings caption starting from the top left and to reshape around the title box. The following code is the closest I got (inspired by [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483289/how-to-use-lstlisting-with-tcolorbox) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/305392))...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings, breakable, skins}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ttdefault=true]{AnonymousPro}
\definecolor{pblue}{rgb}{0.13,0.13,1}
\definecolor{pgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}


\newtcblisting[auto counter]{code}[4][]{
    enhanced,
    attach boxed title to top right={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight},
    boxed title style={
        size=small,colback=gray!50,
        colframe=gray!50,
        sharp corners=downhill,
        arc=.5cm,
        top=1mm,bottom=1mm,left=1mm,right=1mm
    },
    fonttitle=\color{black}\itshape\ttfamily,
    colframe=gray!20,
    top=\tcboxedtitleheight,
    bottom=\smallskipamount,
    sharp corners=downhill,
    arc=.5cm,
    overlay={
        \begin{tcbclipinterior}
            \fill[gray!25](frame.south west)
            rectangle ([xshift=5.1mm]frame.north west);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}},
    listing remove caption=false,
    listing only,
    listing options={
        numbers=left, 
        numberstyle=\tiny, 
        captionpos=t,
        language=#3,
        xleftmargin=0.6em,
        basicstyle=\fontfamily{AnonymousPro}\selectfont,
        keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{pblue},
        stringstyle=\bfseries\itshape\color{green!40!black},
        commentstyle=\bfseries\itshape\color{black!60},
        showspaces=false,
        showtabs=false,
        breaklines=true,
        showstringspaces=false,
        tabsize=1,
        caption=#4,
        % emph={
        %     downto, for, String, TextView, Toast, Button, EditText, ImageView, Typeface, Intent, WebView, WebSettings, SwipeRefreshLayout, RelativeLayout, Animation, AlertDialog, SharedPreferences, Editor, ToggleButton, CardView, LinearLayout, gradient, shape,
        % },
        emphstyle={\bfseries\color{pblue}},  
    },
    title=#2,
    #1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{code}{Hello Java}{Java}{My caption}
String s = "Hello World";

Animation from_top = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.from_top);
imageView.setAnimation(from_top);

// change activity with fade animation

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in,R.anim.fade_out);
        finish();
    }
}, SPLASH_TIMEOUT);
\end{code}

\end{document}
```

Which results in...

[image: tcblistings]

Is there any way to control the position and style of the lstlistings caption inside the tcolorbox to achieve the desired result? Alternatively, how can I define another caption apart from the listing's one to achieve the same result?

Additionally, is it possible to modify things so that I can specify the environment like...

```
\begin{code}[lang={LANG}, title={TITLE}, caption={CAPTION},...}
code here
\end{code}
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I hoped to get by with `caption`, but it doesn't interact with `tcolorbox`.

Do it the hard way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings, breakable, skins}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ttdefault=true]{AnonymousPro}


\definecolor{pblue}{rgb}{0.13,0.13,1}
\definecolor{pgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{code}{%
  \long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
    \vskip\abovecaptionskip
    #1: #2\par
    \vskip\belowcaptionskip
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newtcblisting[auto counter]{code}[4][]{
    enhanced,
    attach boxed title to top right={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight},
    boxed title style={
        size=small,colback=gray!50,
        colframe=gray!50,
        sharp corners=downhill,
        arc=.5cm,
        top=1mm,bottom=1mm,left=1mm,right=1mm
    },
    fonttitle=\color{black}\itshape\ttfamily,
    colframe=gray!20,
    top=\tcboxedtitleheight,
    bottom=\smallskipamount,
    sharp corners=downhill,
    arc=.5cm,
    overlay={
        \begin{tcbclipinterior}
            \fill[gray!25](frame.south west)
            rectangle ([xshift=5.1mm]frame.north west);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}},
    listing remove caption=false,
    listing only,
    listing options={
        numbers=left, 
        numberstyle=\tiny, 
        captionpos=t,
        abovecaptionskip=0pt,
        belowcaptionskip=\medskipamount,
        language=#3,
        xleftmargin=0.6em,
        basicstyle=\fontfamily{AnonymousPro}\selectfont,
        keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{pblue},
        stringstyle=\bfseries\itshape\color{green!40!black},
        commentstyle=\bfseries\itshape\color{black!60},
        showspaces=false,
        showtabs=false,
        breaklines=true,
        showstringspaces=false,
        tabsize=1,
        caption=#4,
        % emph={
        %     downto, for, String, TextView, Toast, Button, EditText, ImageView, Typeface, Intent, WebView, WebSettings, SwipeRefreshLayout, RelativeLayout, Animation, AlertDialog, SharedPreferences, Editor, ToggleButton, CardView, LinearLayout, gradient, shape,
        % },
        emphstyle={\bfseries\color{pblue}},  
    },
    title=#2,
    #1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{code}{Hello Java}{Java}{My caption}
String s = "Hello World";

Animation from_top = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.from_top);
imageView.setAnimation(from_top);

// change activity with fade animation

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in,R.anim.fade_out);
        finish();
    }
}, SPLASH_TIMEOUT);
\end{code}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. That looks like progress. Do you think it'd be possible to get the caption above the tcolorbox, and have it say, in bold, "Code Snippet i" (where i is the number code snippet in the document)?

Comment: @user41177 That's a completely different business.

Comment: In that case, would it be easier to try and turn what is currently the title into an overlay (or something else), and make the caption the title?