# How to add a second overlay to a tcolorbox?

Tags: tcolorbox, tcblisting

I have the following MWE (inspired by inspired by [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483289/how-to-use-lstlisting-with-tcolorbox) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/305392))...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings, breakable, skins}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ttdefault=true]{AnonymousPro}
\definecolor{pblue}{rgb}{0.13,0.13,1}
\definecolor{pgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\renewcommand*\thelstnumber{\makebox[3em][r]{\ifnum\value{lstnumber}<10 0\fi\the\value{lstnumber}}}


% create non-copy numbers (source - https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57160)
\usepackage[space=true]{accsupp}
\newcommand{\copyablespace}{\BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=00A0}\hphantom{x}\EndAccSupp{}}
\newcommand\donotcopy[1]{% line number printing mechanism
  \BeginAccSupp{ActualText={}}#1\EndAccSupp{}%
}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtcblisting[auto counter]{code}[4][]{
    enhanced,
    attach boxed title to bottom right={
        yshift=\baselineskip + 1mm,xshift=-2.5mm
    },
    boxed title style={
        size=small,colback=gray!50,
        colframe=gray!50,
        % sharp corners=downhill,
        % arc=.5cm,
        top=-1pt,bottom=-1pt,left=-1pt,right=-1pt
    },
    fonttitle=\scriptsize\color{violet}\itshape\ttfamily,
    colframe=gray!20,
    top=\smallskipamount,
    bottom=\smallskipamount,
    sharp corners=downhill,
    arc=.5cm,
    overlay={
        \begin{tcbclipinterior}
            \fill[gray!25](frame.south west)
            rectangle ([xshift=5mm]frame.north west);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}},
    % listing remove caption=false,
    listing only,
    listing options={
        numbers=left, 
        numberstyle=\ttfamily\tiny\donotcopy, 
        captionpos=t,
        language=#3,
        xleftmargin=0.5em,
        basicstyle=\fontfamily{AnonymousPro}\selectfont,
        keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{pblue},
        stringstyle=\bfseries\itshape\color{green!40!black},
        commentstyle=\bfseries\itshape\color{black!50},
        showspaces=false,
        showtabs=false,
        breaklines=true,
        columns=fullflexible,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily,
        literate={*}{{\char42}}1
         {-}{{\char45}}1
         {\ }{{\copyablespace}}1,
        showstringspaces=false,
        tabsize=1,
        caption={#4},
        emphstyle={\bfseries\color{pblue}},  
    },
    title=#2,
    #1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{code}{\faJava \ \raisebox{0.1\height}{Hello.Java}}{Java}{Porzione di codice che riporta il tipo enumerazione nel file standard.h di bitcoin core.}
String s = "Hello World";

Animation from_top = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.from_top);
imageView.setAnimation(from_top);

// change activity with fade animation

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in,R.anim.fade_out);
        finish();
    }
}, SPLASH_TIMEOUT);
\end{code}

% 
\end{document}
```

It currently looks like...

[image: now]

I want it to look approximately like...
[image: objective]

I want what is currently the title box to be a second optional overlay (or something else that is more appropriate?) How can I do this?

**EDIT**

I found out multiple things can be placed in an overlay, ie, changing the overlay to...

```
overlay={
        \begin{tcbclipinterior}
            \fill[gray!25](frame.south west)
            rectangle ([xshift=5.0mm]frame.north west);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}
        \node[anchor=north east, draw, very thick,tcbcolframe,fill=tcbcolback] at ([xshift=-2.5mm, yshift=\baselineskip]frame.south east){(#2)};
        }
```

I end up getting a box that looks like...

[image: new overlay]

I now just need help restyling the box.

Comment: sorry, don't get your point. Can you please add a mockup-drawing, what you are looking for? Thank you

Comment: I added an approximation and updated my source. I appreciate it.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483289/how-to-use-lstlisting-with-tcolorbox?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @jsbibra That is one of the links in my post. That's how I got the shape of the tcolorbox. I changed the title box to the one shown in my working example. Now I want to switch that title box w/ an overlay, while keeping the overlay for my line numbers, and adding a more standard looking title above the tcblisting.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with the format that I wanted via...

```
\newtcblisting[auto counter]{code}[4][]{
    enhanced,
    top=\smallskipamount,
    bottom=\smallskipamount,
    sharp corners=downhill,
    arc=0.5cm,
    colframe=gray!20,
    attach boxed title to top left={
        % yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight - \smallskipamount,
        xshift=-2mm
    },
    boxed title style={
        size=small,
        colback=white,
        colframe=white,
        boxrule=0pt,
        top=0pt,
        bottom=0pt,
        right=0pt,
        left=0pt
    },
    fonttitle=\color{black},
    overlay={
        \begin{tcbclipinterior}
            \fill[gray!25](frame.south west)
            rectangle ([xshift=5.0mm]frame.north west);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}
        \node[inner sep=0.75mm, rounded corners=0.5mm, anchor=north east, ,fill=gray!50] at ([xshift=-2.5mm, yshift=\baselineskip]frame.south east){\scriptsize\color{violet}\itshape\ttfamily#2};
        },
    listing only,
    listing options={
        numbers=left, 
        numberstyle=\ttfamily\tiny\donotcopy, 
        captionpos=t,
        abovecaptionskip=0pt,
        belowcaptionskip=\medskipamount,
        language=#3,
        xleftmargin=0.5em,
        basicstyle=\fontfamily{AnonymousPro}\selectfont,
        keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{pblue},
        stringstyle=\bfseries\itshape\color{green!40!black},
        commentstyle=\bfseries\itshape\color{black!60},
        showspaces=false,
        showtabs=false,
        breaklines=true,
        showstringspaces=false,
        tabsize=1,
        emphstyle={\bfseries\color{pblue}},
        columns=fullflexible,
        literate={\ }{{\copyablespace}}1,
    },
    title=\ifx #4\empty\empty\else\ \textbf{Code Snippet~\thetcbcounter.} #4\fi,
    #1
}
```

which ends up producing...

[image: answer]